# Convergence of metric sequence to 0

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $M$, and $l ∈ M$. Prove that $(x_n)$ converges to $l$ if and only if the sequence of real numbers $(d(x_n,l))$ converges to $0$.

I'm able to prove right to left but not left to right. I've tried using contradiction but I'm not sure how to set up an appropriate radius

Side question: How does one include MathJax formatting in one's question?

Comment: write the meaning of $x_n \to l$ in $d$ notation..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=l$ means$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists N\in\Bbb N):n\geqslant N\implies d(x_n,l)<\varepsilon\tag1$$and the assertion $\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,l)=0$ means$$(\forall\varepsilon>0)(\exists N\in\Bbb N):n\geqslant N\implies|d(x_n,l)-0|<\varepsilon.\tag2$$Since $|d(x_n,l)-0|=d(x_n,l)$, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are the same assertion.

Comment: Does |d(xn,l)−0| work even if its not in R? The question asks for an arbitrary metric space so wouldnt it have to be d(d(xn,l)−0) = d(xn,l) ?

Comment: It's for an arbitrary metric on $M$, but for the usual metric on $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Left to right: 
Given that $x_n \to l$ and therefore $\forall \epsilon \gt 0, \exists N_\epsilon \in \mathbb N: n\ge N_\epsilon\implies d(x_n,l)\lt \epsilon\implies |d(x_n,l)-0|\lt \epsilon $

Comment: Does |d(xn,l)−0| work even if its not in R? The question asks for an arbitrary metric space so wouldnt it have to be d(d(xn,l)−0) = d(xn,l) ?

Comment: @user46578: It does.  Why? It is because $d(x_n,l)$ is a real no. and 0 is an additive identity of real nos.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming $(M,d)$ is a metric space and will use the continuity of $d$. Since the sequence $\{(x_n, l)\}_n$ in $M^2$ converges to $(l,l)$, so $d(x_n,l)$ will converge  to $d(l,l)=0$.